# React native difference in react native project directry structure

Tags: react-native

While creating an app in react native, I didn't get sub directories like android,or IOS. I Used create-react-native-app command. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of CRNA integrates Expo Toolkit, and `android` and `ios` folders are hidden. If you want to separate these folders, you must detach expo from react native app.

```
npm run reject
```

You can read more detail at [CRNA's github](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app)

Comment: then after this how can I start the project

Comment: Just run `npm start` in a command line window, then run `npm run android` or `npm run ios` in another tab (keep first tab running). If you continue to use Expo, you need to install Expo app from app store, e.g https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en. In `npm start` window, a QR code will be rendered, then scan the QR code in Expo app to run the app. You can live debug app in device, connected by wifi network